# Formatting currency in PHP/MySQL with TWIG

Tags: php, mysql, templates, templating, twig

I am using Twig templating language to develop a small, template-driven site.

Everything works well for the basics - followed the instructions at http://devzone.zend.com/article/13633-Creating-Web-Page-Templates-with-PHP-and-Twig-part-1-

However, I'm having trouble with two things; one, I want my .tpl (template) files outside the templates directory in my scripts, and two, how would I format currency within PHPMyadmin?

This is my script:

cars.tpl:

```
    <html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
      }        
      tr.heading {      
        font-weight: bolder;
      }        
      td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 0 0.5em;
      }    
    </style>  
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Countries and capitals</h2>
    <table>
      <tr class="heading">
        <td>Manufacturer</td>
        <td>Specification</td>
        <td>Price</td>
      </tr> 
      {% for d in data %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ d.car|escape }}</td>
        <td>{{ d.spec|escape }}</td>
        <td>{{ d.price|escape }}</td>
      </tr> 
      {% endfor %}
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

and this is the PHP Twig script:

```
<?php
// include and register Twig auto-loader
include 'Twig/Autoloader.php';
Twig_Autoloader::register();

// attempt a connection
try {
  $dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname=whatcar1;host=localhost', 'root', 'PASSWORD');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo "Error: Could not connect. " . $e->getMessage();
}

// set error mode
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// attempt some queries
try {
  // execute SELECT query
  // store each row as an object
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM vehicles";
  $sth = $dbh->query($sql);
  while ($row = $sth->fetchObject()) {
    $data[] = $row;
  }

  // close connection, clean up
  unset($dbh); 

  // define template directory location
  $loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('templates');

  // initialize Twig environment
  $twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);

  // load template
  $template = $twig->loadTemplate('cars.tpl');

  // set template variables
  // render template
  echo $template->render(array (
    'data' => $data
  ));

} catch (Exception $e) {
  die ('ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

The database is stored in the following manner, with these fields:

```
car VARCHAR 255
spec VARCHAR 255
price VARCHAR 255
```

The field price does not display, even though the SQL query **selects all fields**.

Where have I gone wrong, and how should I attempt to fix this error?
Also, I store the .tpl files outside the template directory, how would I integrate this into the scripts I'm running?

Otherwise, all is going well, and this templating should be useful to my small-scale site!

Answer (score 0):

First off: you should use the appropriate field types in MySQL, for example a `DECIMAL` for the price.

#### Templates outside the templates directory

You define the templates directory in your `Twig_Loader_Filesystem`. You cannot load templates outside this directory - you could however modify the path, given in the constructor.

#### Format currency

It does not seem, that there is anything similar built in.
You could use the filter [`number_format`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/number_format.html) if that is sufficient.
Another solution would be to create an own filter or function and do the magic in there. Your filter/function could call the PHP function [`money_format()`](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.money-format.php), which does most of the work for you.